# Java Firebase Admin SDK connect behind proxy

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am new in firebase development, I'am trying to save a data to realtime database, but it always throw an error when I connected behind my company proxy, I already tried [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) approach but still no luck,

here my stack trace :

```
4517 [firebase-websocket-worker] ERROR 
com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection - [ws_1] 
WebSocket error
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection 
refused: no further information: testing- 
5786c.firebaseio.com/35.201.97.85:443
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:325)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
... 16 more
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Database access takes place over a WebSocket (protocol `wss`) connection. So the usual JVM HTTP proxy settings probably have no effect here. Have you tried using a custom `ProxySelector` (option 4 in the page you've shared)? That is the solution most likely to work in this case.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka hi, thanks for the hint, I let you know if it succeed.

Comment: Whether the solution suggested by @HiranyaJayathilaka worked for you..? I am also stuck with same issue.

Comment: @MonishKamble Hi monish, it doesn't work, so in the end I'm using firebase Rest API to communicate https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database